# Boot Ubuntu in Command line without loading graphics drivers?

Tags: boot, grub2, graphics

How do I tell GRUB to boot Ubuntu in command-line and **not to** load any AMD graphics drivers?

It seems that my laptop's Graphics card is broken - there are [blue stripes](http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/graphic-cards/23687d1372350290t-radeon-hd-7950-vertical-stripe-blue-screen-crash-image.jpg). I am able to get to the GRUB menu with these blue stripes. However, once I chose "recovery mode" the screen just freezes and cursor keeps blinking forever. My goal is to somehow boot into system and copy all personal files to a remote host, but I can't do that presumably because Ubuntu tries to load AMD GPU driver and switches graphics mode. The same issue happens also If I try to boot my system with USB flash drive.

Comment: Also as the root cause probably is a hardware defect of your graphics card, maybe cooling it down can temporarily improve the display quality to help you getting your data off. Had a similar issue on an old notebook once and there the amount of artefacts was proportional to the device temperature.

Comment: @ByteCommander I can't get into the original system anymore to type "update-grub" so at least the answer in that question does not fit my needs.

Comment: You can also edit the boot options from the GRUB menu by pressing the `e` key while having the entry you want to modify selected.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out myself. I just had to create an Ubuntu **Server** (and not **Desktop**) flash drive. Then I was able to successfully boot in rescue command line.

It seems that busybox shell environment on Ubuntu server image does not come with `scp` tool. So I just had to let the recovery tools to mount the previous partition to be able to copy over my files to a backup server.